# chrome dispatching wheel event

Tags: google-chrome, events, mousewheel, dispatch

I'm trying to dispatch a wheel event in chrome but still can't make it. I am using the WheelEvent object but seems that just cannot "init" it right. Whatever I do, delta is always 0. I looked at the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20071221/events.html#Events-MouseWheelEvent-wheelDelta), but no help. More interesting, I captured the event when I actually scroll with mouse wheel and tried to dispatch that event, but again the deltas were 0. Did anyone encountered such problem? Is this maybe a bug? Any help would be great!

```
//dispatching the wheel event
var evt = document.createEvent("WheelEvent");
evt.initEvent("mousewheel", true, true, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null, -120);
window.dispatchEvent(evt)

// catching the wheel event
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', callback, true);
callback = function(evt){
       console.log(evt)
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us some code. How are you registering the event listener, or are you just setting a callback? How are you dispatching the event?

Comment: I added the code. Event is catched, but page is not scrolled because deltas are 0.

Comment: Ok, I've founded the reason. I was using the wrong init function. The right one is [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/WebKitDOMRef/WheelEvent_idl/Classes/WheelEvent/index.html). But still my page refuses to scroll down.

Comment: @bellpeace, did you ever figure this out? And what's the right init function? Unfortunately your link is dead.

Comment: @AndrewB., I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I didn't need anymore this functionality but I recently got back to this issue and found a way to dispatch wheel event properly on Chrome. Sorry for the delay, I totally forgot about this issue. The code is as follows:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("WheelEvent");
evt.initWebKitWheelEvent(deltaX, deltaY, window, screenX, screenY, clientX,
                        clientY, ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey);
node.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work any more as it was taken out of Chrome: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/initWebkitWheelEvent$20/blink-dev/h_GoezQ4MQ4/Q5abFkhA76sJ